# AChartEngine Multiple Y Axis overlapping Values

Tags: android, axis, overlap, achartengine

i use the AChartEngine as a library to draw my line Charts. This Line-Chart consists of Multiple Y-Axis (3-5 Axis) and goes on a Timeline on the X-Axis.

My Problem is, that Y-Axis-Values are overlapping (see image)

Heres my code:

```
//Puls, Geschwindigkeit und Hoehenmeter dem Diagramm hinzufugen
        HashMap<Long, Heartrate> heartrateMap = trainingLog.getHeartrateList();
        HashMap<Long, GPS> gpsMap = trainingLog.getGpsList();
        //Puls, Geschwindigkeit und Hoehenmeter dem Diagramm hinzufugen
        XYSeries heartrateSeries = new XYSeries("Puls", 0);
        XYSeries altitudeSeries = new XYSeries("Höhenmeter", 1);
        XYSeries speedSeries = new XYSeries("Geschwindigkeit", 2);

        for(int i=0; i<trainingLog.getDuration(); i++){
            Heartrate heartrate = heartrateMap.get(Long.valueOf(i));
            if(heartrate != null){
                heartrateSeries.add(i, heartrate.getHeartrate());
            }

            GPS gps = gpsMap.get(Long.valueOf(i));
            if(gps != null){
                altitudeSeries.add(i, gps.getAltitude());
                speedSeries.add(i, gps.getSpeed());
            }
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataSet.addSeries(0, heartrateSeries);
        dataSet.addSeries(1, altitudeSeries);
        dataSet.addSeries(2, speedSeries);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(3);

        //Renderer fuer Pulswerte
        XYSeriesRenderer rendererHeartrate = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererHeartrate.setColor(Color.RED);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererHeartrate);
        //Renderer fuer Hoehenmeter
        XYSeriesRenderer rendererAltitude = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererAltitude.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererAltitude);
        //Renderer fuer Geschwindigkeit
        XYSeriesRenderer rendererSpeed = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererSpeed.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererSpeed);

        //Hintergrundfarbe weiß setzen
        multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));

        //Label--Einstellungen
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.RED);
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(1, Color.BLUE);
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(2, Color.DKGRAY);
        multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);

        int length = multiRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeriesRenderer r = (XYSeriesRenderer) multiRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
            r.setLineWidth(2f);
        }

        //Legenden-Einstellungen
        multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);

        multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 20, 20, 20});

        Looper.prepare();
        graphicalView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataSet, multiRenderer);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? The best way would be to set the y-labels parallel to each other, but i havent found a way to do this. Or is there a function to set the margin of each y-label to the y-axis?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could set different alignments for your Y axis labels. For instance, the first series would align the labels on the left, the second one on the right and the third on center.

```
multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but this method i already tried. As you can see on the following image the overlapping is still there: http://postimage.org/image/bxywmw8q3/

Comment: AChartEngine doesn't offer other overlapping protection than the one I mentioned.

Comment: Do you know if another library can handle this? I just tried the GrapView but they dont support multiple y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set y axis minimum value and maximum value for all three scales you used.

Then change color of two Y scales to transparent using Color.argb